# How to copy several lines from a buffer to another in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

I have two buffers. I want to copy the line 2, 5, 9 and 10 in the first buffer to the second buffer(just append to the second buffer). Except copy and past one line at a time, is there any elegant way to do so?

Comment: Is that an arbitrary example, or a specific case you wish to repeat many times with those line numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution would be recording a macro that copies a line from one buffer to another ( <kbd>f3 C-SCP C-n M-w C-x o C-y C-x o f4</kbd>) and then execute the macro (<kbd>f4</kbd>)on every line you want to copy.

If this is a recurring scenario for you, you can save the macro and bind it to a key.

Comment: That's the answer I want. Also, just learnt how to use micro.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the command `append-next-kill`, bound to `C-M-w`, to add more text to the latest entry on the kill ring.  Use it right before a `M-w` command, something like this:

- Mark and copy line 2: `C-SPC`, `C-n`, `M-w`
- Move to line 5
- Mark and append-copy it: `C-SPC`, `C-n`, `C-M-w`, `M-w`
- Move to line 9...

...and so on.

When you yank the text with `C-y`, you'll get the lines you selected and appended to the kill ring entry all together.

Answer (score 4):

For off-the-shelf functionality, I would recommend looking at `multiple-cursors.el`.  It's particularly effective when you have a symbol/regexp that you need to select and modify in multiple places.

https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el

However, it can also handle specific lines/points through its generic add cursor function:

`mc/add-cursor-on-click`

But this means you have to bind it to a mouse event (as recommended in the Tips section):

`(global-set-key (kbd "C-S-<mouse-1>") 'mc/add-cursor-on-click)`

It means you have to reach for the mouse, but it looks pretty easy to create a new function `mc/add-cursor-at-line`:

```
(defun mc/add-cursor-at-line (&optional linenum)
  (interactive "nLine number: ")
  (save-excursion 
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (forward-line (1- linenum))
    (mc/create-fake-cursor-at-point))
  (mc/maybe-multiple-cursors-mode))
```

Then, once you have multiple cursors setup on all your lines:

**Copy all cursors:**
<kbd>C-SPC</kbd> <kbd>C-e</kbd> <kbd>M-w</kbd> <kbd>RET</kbd>

Switch buffers and...

**Yank Rectangle:** <kbd>C-x r y</kbd>

Comment: Nice. I hadn't noticed that multiple cursors uses `killed-rectangle`. That library *really* needs a nice way to 'mark' a bunch of cursors-to-be in single-cursor mode, and then switch into multiple cursor mode to edit with them. You can kinda do this by setting marks and calling `mc/pop-mark` repeatedly, but that's clunkier than it could be.

Comment: @assem, you could use `(interactive "nLine number: ")` to save a couple of lines in your function.

Comment: @juanleon, excellent, thanks.  i've updated the sample as you suggested

Comment: @phils, i'd also like to see that functionality; what about inserting a text property at all points of interest, then activation accumulates a list of the points for that prop, mapcar/loop over the list with a `mc/add-cursor-at-point` function instead.  whatever the solution, it would be worthwhile to get it into mc =)

Comment: assem: [Previously discussed in its issue queue](https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el/issues/44), I see; but the mouse-based approach seems like the only standard interactive approach which came from that.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the exact use case, I would probably copy the whole region from the first line to the last line inclusively, and then kill those lines that I don't need in the new buffer.

- **1. move to beginning of first line to copy**
- **2.** <kbd>C-space</kbd> *set mark to begin marking a region*
- **3. move the end of the last line to copy**
- **4.** <kbd>M-w</kbd> *copy region*
- **5.** <kbd>C-x b</kbd> **buffer-name** <kbd>RET</kbd> *go to second buffer*
- **6. move to insertion position in second buffer**
- **7.** <kbd>C-y</kbd> *insert (yank) region*
- **8.** <kbd>C-x C-x</kbd> *go to beginning of yanked region*
- **9.** <kbd>C-n</kbd> *repeat until you get to first unwanted line*
- **10.** <kbd>C-k C-k</kbd> *delete unwanted line*
- **11.** *goto 9 until done*

If there are longer stretches of unwanted lines to be delete in the new buffer, steps 9. through 11. should be replaced by something like:

- **9. move to beginning of longer stretch of unwanted lines**
- **10.** <kbd>C-space</kbd> *set mark to begin marking a region*
- **11. move to end of longer stretch of unwanted lines**
- **12.** <kbd>C-w</kbd> *kill region*
- **13.** *goto 9 until done*